# Programmatically set dgrid row as active

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I'm trying to programmatically set a dgrid row as **active**, not just *selected*.  I have a dojo dgrid `OnDemandList` which is using the `Selection` and `Keyboard` Mixins.

Using the `select(row)` method I can programmatically *select* a given row, but that row is not *active*. When a row is *active*, I can use the Up and Down arrow keys to navigate to the rows above and below it. When a row is just *selected*, the row is highlighted but the arrows keys do not work.

Clicking the row with the mouse will make it *active* and *selected*, but I'm trying to build my interface to be 100% usable with just the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, took me awhile but got it figured out. What I was really trying to do was add focus to a row. The code for doing that was in `dgrid/Keyboard.js` under the `_focusOnNode` method.

The actual code to change focus from row `currentFocusedNode` to row `focusedNode` is:

```
if(currentFocusedNode){
    // Clean up previously-focused element
    // Remove the class name and the tabIndex attribute
    put(currentFocusedNode, "!dgrid-focus[!tabIndex]");
    if(has("ie") < 8){
        // Clean up after workaround below (for non-input cases)
        currentFocusedNode.style.position = "";
    }
}

if(has("ie") < 8){
    // setting the position to relative magically makes the outline
    // work properly for focusing later on with old IE.
    // (can't be done a priori with CSS or screws up the entire table)
    focusedNode.style.position = "relative";
}
focusedNode.tabIndex = grid.tabIndex;
focusedNode.focus();
put(focusedNode, ".dgrid-focus");
```

The code above is really just a code fragment, for it to work you will have to declare `"dojo/has"` and `"put-selector/put"` first as well as define the `currentFocusedNode` and `focusedNode`. But I'm leaving that as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Also note that this only changes the "focus", it will not select the `focusedNode` but that can easily be done using `grid.select(focusedNode);`